# Access the internal clock on WLAN chips

Tags: clock, wifi

I am trying to implement a localization method based on WLAN round trip time (RTT) ranging. Some of the papers I have read suggest doing ranging based on the MAC layer RTTs (beacons, ACK, RTS/CTS etc.) However, the MAC layer time resolution is only 1µs. Relatively accurate ranging can still be performed by taking upwards of a 1000 measurements and doing some statistical analysis on the resulting Gaussian distribution.

However, some papers mention using the internal clock of the WLAN module as time basis for ranging. These clocks typically have a time resolution of only a few ns, which would greatly increase accuracy.

My question is:

How can I access these internal clocks in the WLAN modules? All the round trip time measurement tools I have come across so far (libpcap, wireshark) only give MAC layer based information with the 1µs resolution. 
Can anyone point me in a direction towards resources, code or anything that will help me capture the send/receive time of a beacon message, ACK, or RTS/CTS with regards to the internal clock? Has anyone here successfully accessed and read that clock and would be wiling to give me some pointers?

Comment: Are you talking about the Wifi radio chipset (usually with an SDIO or USB interface) or a Wifi module (usually with a UART and/or SPI interface)? Can you add a link to whatever hardware you're working with?

Comment: I am talking about the chipset. I am working with a Ralink 802.11 n WLAN USB dongle at the moment. However, should it be possible to do this with other hardware I would be willing to switch to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make contact with the chipset vendor and ask whether their USB commandset supports extracting the timing information.  If it does, and if they agree to give you access to it, you would then need to write your own USB driver that implements support for the required commands.